# past perfect or past simple in this introduction to the "This Heat" record called Deceit

Tags: past-tense

> Deceit was the final "This Heat" record and developed out of the previous works as well as pushing our collective process into a wider zone. It was the result of work over the previous year or so, although several of the songs **were already developed** at the same time as the first album.

This is a text written for the reissue of "This Heat"'s second album called Deceit.

I wonder why it is not written "had been already developed" as the songs they are talking about had already been developed at the time of first album. So past simple means that some of the songs were not developed at the time of the first album  and were developed after just before releasing Deceit.

Comment: Can you please fix the quote? It's clear that your transcription of the text is faulty considering that there are many errors in spelling and word choice. It's not possible for us to really address this until we know what the actual content you're quoting says. If at all possible, you should copy and paste the text rather than writing it yourself.

Comment: Please also include a link to the source, as many times we need to check the context to provide the best answer.

Comment: The words ***were already*** don't really work here - better might be *several of the songs **had already been** developed at the same time as the first album*. But I don't much like ***already*** however it's rephrased, because it clashes with ***at the same time*** in terms of "temporal sequence".

Comment: I have just double checked and it is written were already developed  .Sorry can't give a link as the text comes from a little booklet to introduce the lp . Here are the mistake I have done    This Heat, work not works. I don't see any other  mistakes

Comment: @user5577 Please edit your answer to correct  the mistakes you discovered.

Comment: There's no way that the booklet reads "the final this Heat record".

Comment: @Catija, the band is called **This Heat**, and their second and final album is called **Deceit**. The booket should read "'Deceit' was the final 'This Heat' record...".

Comment: @JavaLatte Well, that certainly helps... and it's why capitalization is so important... I was confused because I could have sworn there was a classic rock band called "The Heat"... but now I can't find them... and the OP never calls the band "This Heat", only ever "Heat".

Comment: @Catija, the OP does actually refer to the band as "the Heat" in the second paragraph. Maybe that's what planted the idea in your head.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is anything unusual about **were already** + past participle. Here is an Ngram for [were already](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=N0ZdOPQfmvQC&pg=PA113&dq=%22were%20already%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjkuGOnunMAhWJDBoKHcbfAkkQ6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=%22were%20already%22&f=false), and here is a typical example from [Social Work and Assessment with Adolescents](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=N0ZdOPQfmvQC&pg=PA113&dq=%22were%20already%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjkuGOnunMAhWJDBoKHcbfAkkQ6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=%22were%20already%22&f=false):

> As we saw in the previous chapter, nearly two-thirds of the young people in our study **were already involved** with social services at the time when the 'event' took place, more than a quarter of them for six months or longer

The problem lies in the text that follows this. Depending on what was intended, it should probably have been one of these two:

> Several of the songs were already developed at the time of the first album
>
> Several of the songs were developed at the same time as the first album

The former would suggest that the songs already existed when the first album was released: the latter that the songs were developed in parallel with those of the first album.

The use of the word **our** in the text suggests that it is a quote from one of the artists: in spoken English, we don't always manage to make sentences that join up grammatically.

Comment: The problem with this phrasing is that it doesn't work with what comes after. "Were already developed" **is** fine but adding "at the same time as the first album" seems off.

Comment: Agreed @Catija, I have extended my answer to suggest where the problem lies.

Comment: yes but the reference time is their second album Deceit ,so it is past of the past for the songs that existed at the time of the first album. I double checked and it is "at the same time as the first album"